# RedHat Fuse 7.5 - Can't deploy feature

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

Using RedHat Fuse 7.5 for Apache Karaf platform on Windows 10. I'm defining the feature shown below:

```
  ...
  <feature name="customers-data" version="${project.version}">
    <feature>transaction</feature>
    <feature>jndi</feature>
    <feature>pax-jdbc-config</feature>
    <feature>pax-jdbc-oracle</feature>
    <feature>pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2</feature>
    <feature>jdbc</feature>
    <feature dependency="true">aries-blueprint</feature>
    <feature>jpa</feature>
    <feature>hibernate</feature>
    <bundle>...</bundle>
  </feature>
  ...
```

Adding the the new repo works as expected but trying to install the feature:

```
karaf@root()> feature:install customers-data
```

raises the following exception:

```
2019-12-12 17:43:02,385 | WARN  | ownloader-5-thread-7 | o.o.p.u.m.i.AetherBasedResolver  | 5 - org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn - 2.6.1 | Error resolving artifact 
org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence:javax.persistence_2.1:jar:2.7.2: [Could not transfer artifact org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence:javax.persistence_2.1:jar:2.7.2 from/to maven.central.repo 
(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.36.209] failed: connect timed out, Could not transfer artifact 
org.apache.aries.jpa.javax.persistence:javax.persistence_2.1:jar:2.7.2 from/to redhat.ga.repo 
(https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/): Connect to maven.repository.redhat.com:443 
[maven.repository.redhat.com/23.60.31.183] failed: connect timed out
```

Looking up the features I got this:

```
karaf@root()> feature:list | grep aries-jpa
jpa                                      | 2.7.2                           |          | Uninstalled | aries-jpa-2.7.2                               | OSGi Persistence Container
karaf@root()>
```

So the feature aries-jpa-2.7.2 is registered. Trying to install it:

```
karaf@root()> feature:install jpa
```

raises the same exception as mentioned above.

Could any one please shad some light here ?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,

Nicolas

Comment: You have connect timeout when accessing https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 - can you access it from your browser?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the fact that Karaf doesn't use the local maven install and its settings but its own one. So, when behind an HTTP proxy, as it was my case, one needs either to configure Karaf to use the HTTP proxy or to tell it to use the local maven settings. This happens in $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg file.